# Problems installing Ratchet with Composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, ratchet

I've been following the guides [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/) and [here](http://socketo.me/docs/install) and I get a `composer.json`, a `composer.phar` and a `vendor` folder including `composer`, `evenement`, `guzzle`, `react` and `symfony`.

But no `vendor/autoload.php` and no `vendor/ratchet`

Comment: can you post your composer.json files?

Comment: @Matteo Sure. I updated it myself though to add the autoload part `{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "MyApp": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.3.6"
    }
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put in an empty dir a composer.json files with the content you provided and the result is the following:

[image: dir structure]

Probably the process didn't fully success, **try removing the content of the `vendor` dir and retry.**

Hope this help

Comment: This time I got this: `All settings correct for using Composer
Unable to write keys.dev.pub to: /home/seabass/.composer`

Comment: And then `$ php ~/composer.phar require cboden/ratchet
Could not open input file: /home/seabass/composer.phar`

Comment: Aha `sudo su` did the trick! But I got a message saying "Do not run composer as root/super user" hehe. Well, it installed. How should I have solved it?